# Spring Security 4 extending the custom filter

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-security, filter

To change the spring security filter I had below

```
<http auto-config="false" entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint">
    <custom-filter before="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="customPasswordAuthenticationFilter"/> 
</http>
```

But I want to change the `FORM_LOGIN_FILTER` so I prefer to use `position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"` but I get the error:

```
Configuration problem: 
Filter beans '<customUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter>' and '<org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0>' have the same 'order' value. 
When using custom filters, please make sure the positions do not conflict with default filters. Alternatively you can disable the default filters by removing the corresponding child elements from <http> and avoiding the use of <http auto-config='true'>.
```

The document mentioned that:

> Attribute : position The explicit position at which the custom-filter
>   should be placed in the chain. Use if you are replacing a standard.

Comment: I think you should remove the auto-config attribute. From [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#ns-config): **auto-config**: Automatically registers a login form, BASIC authentication, logout services. If set to "true", all of these capabilities are added (although you can still customize the configuration of each by providing the respective element). If unspecified, defaults to "false". Use of this attribute is not recommended. Use explicit configuration elements instead to avoid confusion.

Comment: Yes I have tested that but still the same error!